# Update Delimiter of Specific Columns in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, delimiter

I have a CSV file, the number of columns in CSV file is 10. But there is a column which contains **","** in this value. I want to change the delimiter of the file to **"|"** without change data in the column which contains **","**

File I have

```
John Doe,19,England,3653,Manchester, England,Main Worker,20-05-1995

Bill Mark,19, Australia,3653,Main Street, People Two, Perth,Main Worker,20-05-1995

Mark Home,19,USA,3653, Redmond, Ground Town, Main Street, Virginia,Main Worker,20-05-1995
```

Required Output

```
John Doe|19|England|3653|Manchester, England|Part Time Worker|20-05-1995

Bill Mark|19|Australia|3653|Main Street, People Two, Perth|Main Worker,20-05-1995

Mark Home|19|USA|3653| Redmond, Ground Town, Main Street, Virginia|Main Worker|20-05-1995
```

I have tried multiple solutions but not able to achieved what I am looking for. I tried following command which only updates the delimiter of first 4 columns.

```
sed 's/,/|/;s/,/|/;s/,/|/;s/,/|/' file
```

The approach I'm looking for is to update the delimiter of first 4 columns and last 2 columns. In this way I can have the file with updated delimiter and the Address column has no effect on it.

Comment: Your in and out files don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with sed (GNU sed) 4.7 :

```
sed 's/, /\o0/g;s/,/|/g;s/\d0/, /g' file
```

The field separator in your file is the comma but some fields can have a comma in it.
As you can see in your data, the comma in a field never come alone.
Fortunaly there is always a space after it.
So first, convert ', ' to char NUL (\o0]. This char never come in a text file.
After that, convert all comma to '|'
At the end, restore ', '

Or, with GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)

```
awk -F', ' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)gsub(",","|",$i)}1' file
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this command works? So that If want to apply the same command to a larger datasets how it will work?

Comment: @Moiez. What do you mean by larger datasets ? I think it work to.

Answer (score 1):

From the simple example given, the commas you want to keep are the the only ones followed by spaces.

```
$: cat foo
Name,Age,Country,ID,Address,Category,DOB
John Doe,19,England,3653,Manchester, England,Main Worker,20-05-1995
Bill Mark,19, Australia,3653,Main Street, People Two, Perth,Main Worker,20-05-1995
Mark Home,19,USA,3653, Redmond, Ground Town, Main Street, Virginia,Main Worker,20-05-1995

$: sed -E 's/,(\S)/|\1/g' foo
Name|Age|Country|ID|Address|Category|DOB
John Doe|19|England|3653|Manchester, England|Main Worker|20-05-1995
Bill Mark|19, Australia|3653|Main Street, People Two, Perth|Main Worker|20-05-1995
Mark Home|19|USA|3653, Redmond, Ground Town, Main Street, Virginia|Main Worker|20-05-1995
```

This scans for a comma followed by a NONspace, and remembers the following character.
It replaces the commas that match (and the following saved char) with a pipe (and the following saved char). It will ignore commas followed by a space, because they don't match the pattern.

This still works for all the provided examples.
For cases where there are no spaces after the comma, you're going to have to reconstruct the line.

```
$: cat foo
Name,Age,Country,ID,Address,Category,DOB
John Doe,19,England,3653,Manchester, England,Part Time Worker,20-05-1995
Bill Mark,19, Australia,3653,Main Street, People Two, Perth,Main Worker,20-05-1995
Mark Home,19,USA,3653, Redmond, Ground Town, Main Street, Virginia,Main Worker,20-05-1995

$: cat tst
while IFS=, read -a line;                                  # read and split
do set -- "${line[@]}"                                     # set as $1, etc
   for i in 0 1 2 3; do printf "%s|" "$1"; shift;  done;   # print first 4
   while (( 3 < $# )); do printf "%s, " "$1"; shift; done  # all BUT last 3
   printf "%s|" "$1" "$2"                                  # last 2 get |
   echo "$3"                                               # last 1 gets \n
done<foo

$: ./tst
Name|Age|Country|ID|Address|Category|DOB
John Doe|19|England|3653|Manchester,  England|Part Time Worker|20-05-1995
Bill Mark|19| Australia|3653|Main Street,  People Two,  Perth|Main Worker|20- 05-1995
Mark Home|19|USA|3653| Redmond,  Ground Town,  Main Street,  Virginia|Main Worker|20-05-1995
```

Note that doing it this way preserves leading spaces on fields. If you want to strip those you'll need to do it manually, but then you can do it in one pass over the whole file:

```
sed -E 's/[|]\s+/\|/g' file
```

If you really want to trim all leading/trailing whitespace on all fields -

```
sed -E 's/^\s+//; s/\s+[|]\s+/\|/g; s/\s+$//;' file
```

e.g.:

```
$: ./tst|    sed -E 's/[|]\s+/\|/g'
Name|Age|Country|ID|Address|Category|DOB
John Doe|19|England|3653|Manchester,  England|Part Time Worker|20-05-1995
Bill Mark|19|Australia|3653|Main Street,  People Two,  Perth|Main Worker|20-05-1995
Mark Home|19|USA|3653|Redmond,  Ground Town,  Main Street,  Virginia|Main Worker|20-05-1995
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but the thing is number of commas in the address columns is not always the same. They are variable also it is now always the case they appear before a space character. I have added few more samples in the question, can you please check them and suggest a solution accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You may use awk. This kind of script will do the job:

```
t='John Doe,19,England,3653,Manchester, England,Main Worker,20-05-1995'
echo $t | awk '{ORS="";N=split($0,a,",");\
            print a[1]"|"a[2]"|"a[3]"|"a[4]"|"; \
            for(i=5;i<N-1;i++) print a[i]; 
            print "|"a[N-1]"|"a[N] }'
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but this script is removing the comma between Manchester, England. I don't want it to be removed. Is there any solution I can retain it? Thanks